# Proving a differential equation if $y^3-y=2x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, contest-math

I am given that $y^3-y=2x$ and I have to prove the following differential equation. I started off by calculating the derivative and second order derivative. This is way too tedious for an exam question.

> $$\left(x^2-\frac{1}{27}\right)\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}+x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{y}{9}$$

Is there some neat formulation that I am missing. I believe maybe transforming it back to a parametric form would help, possibly if we let $3\sqrt{3}x=\cos\theta$. Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for ideas, or for people doing tedious calculations for you? Why don't you investigate your "possibly if we let $3\sqrt{3}x=\cos\theta$," and tell us what it gave?

Comment: @ProfessorVector It does not seem like a valid replacement since $\cos\theta$ is a bounded function. So I am on the lookout for any neat trick if someone experienced can notice any data in the formulation of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using implicit differentiation,
$$
y' = \frac{2}{3y^2-1};\qquad y'' = \frac{-6y (y')^2}{3y^2-1}
$$Rewrite:
$$
(27x^2-1)y''+27x y'=3y
$$
$$
-(27x^2-1)\cdot \frac{24y}{(3y^2-1)^3}+27x\cdot \frac{2}{3y^2-1}=3y
$$Clear denominators:
$$
-(27(2x)^2-4)\cdot{6y}+27\cdot(3y^2-1)^2\cdot 2x=3y(3y^2-1)^3
$$Use the relation:
$$
-(27(y^3-y)^2-4)\cdot{6y}+27(3y^2-1)^2(y^3-y)=3y(3y^2-1)^3
$$
$$
-2(27(y^3-y)^2-4)+9(y^2-1)(3y^2-1)^2=(3y^2-1)^3
$$At this point, one way to check is to foil everything out and verify things cancel:
$$
-2 ( 3 y^2-4) ( 3 y^2-1)^2+9(y^2-1)(3y^2-1)^2=(3y^2-1)^3
$$
$$
-2 ( 3 y^2-4) +9(y^2-1)=(3y^2-1)
$$
$$
(3y^2-1)=(3y^2-1)
$$ Another way is to observe that both sides are degree six polys; thus if you have equality at seven points, say $\{0,1,-1,-2,2,3,-3\}$, then they're identically equal.

Comment: "Another way is to observe that both sides are degree six polys; thus if you have equality at seven points,... then they're identically equal." Thanks for answering.

Comment: The OP clearly said that they find calculations tedious.

Comment: @ProfessorVector with respect, I feel these are doable calculations, especially on a contest problem. If there is a slick way to see it, I'd be very interested.

Comment: Of course, they are doable, simply the OP prefers *we* do them.